# OpenVPN not connecting; TLS handshake fail

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I'm attempting to set up remote access to my LAN, so on my tplink router I've set up OpenVPN [as per this guide.](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1544/) I also registered for tplink's DDNS service thingy and it gave me a `name.tplinkdns.com` domain.

To test if this works, I hook up my laptop to a tethered wifi connection from my phone (i.e. not on my local network). Running OpenVPN on it (Win10, v2.5.7), it is stuck in 'connecting' state with TLS handshake failing every 1 minute. Here's some logs:

```
Wed Jun 29 20:11:38 2022 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xx.yy.zz.nn:1194
Wed Jun 29 20:11:38 2022 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed Jun 29 20:11:38 2022 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]xx.yy.zz.nn:1194
Wed Jun 29 20:12:38 2022 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed Jun 29 20:12:38 2022 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

I've tried both UDP (as above) and TCP (it gives an 'unknown error' after 60 seconds). I've modified the config file to point directly at the `name.tplinkdns.com` domain I have, but that didn't work either (previously it was pointing at a 10.x.x.x domain, not sure if that matters).

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer for this particular issue was opening the 1194 port on my ISP's router/modem, and that fixed it.